# How to edit and delete a specific node in XML by PHP

Tags: php, xml, edi

I have wasted a lot of my time trying to edit and delete a specific node in an xml file by php. Now I successfully deleted that node, but when I try to edit a node it will update only the last node.

My xml file is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <reviews>
   <product name="NokiaN9White">
      <user name="testuser" id="02232012062451">
         <username>test@test.com</username>
         <date_post>23-02-2012</date_post>
         <date_update>23-02-2012</date_update>
         <review>Hello dear.</review>
      </user>
      <user name="testuser" id="02232012062521">
         <username>test@test.com</username>
         <date_post>23-02-2012</date_post>
         <date_update>23-02-2012</date_update>
         <review>Mrr</review>
      </user>
      <user name="testuser" id="02232012062523">
         <username>test@test.com</username>
         <date_post>23-02-2012</date_post>
         <date_update>23-02-2012</date_update>
         <review>adfasdf</review>
      </user>
   </product>
</reviews>
```

my code for editing this data is:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); 
$xmlDoc->load(dirname(__FILE__)."/reviews.xml");

$products = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName( "product" );
    foreach( $products as $product )
    {
        $prdoductN = $product->getAttribute( "name" );
        if( $prdoductN == $product_name ){

            $users = $product->getElementsByTagName( "user" );

            $userR = get_userName($_SESSION['userName']);
            foreach( $users as $user ){
                $userName = $user->getAttribute( "name" );
                $review_id = $user->getAttribute( "id" );

                if( $userName == $userR && $review_id == $r_id ){

                    $current_date = date('d-m-Y');

                    $eventN = $user->getElementsByTagName("date_update");
                    $eventN->item(0)->nodeValue = $current_date;

                    $eventC = $user->getElementsByTagName("review");
                    $eventC->item(0)->nodeValue = $comments;

                }
            }

            $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
            //$xmlDoc->saveXML(); // This will return the XML as a string
            $xmlDoc->save(dirname(__FILE__)."/reviews.xml");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP extension provided by Zorba to implement your example:

```
declare namespace a = "http://www.zorba-xquery.com/annotations";

declare variable $doc := <reviews>...</reviews>;

declare %a:sequential function local:remove-user(
    $doc as element(reviews), $name as xs:string, $id as xs:string
) as element(reviews)
{
    delete node $doc//user[@name = $name and @id = $id];
    $doc
};

local:remove-user($doc, "testuser", "02232012062523")
```

You can try your example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#2awjZFgWFxoIi7uE2J4HgwUQUuA=

Instruction on how to install the XQuery extension with PHP are available at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2011/12/27/PHP_Meets_XQuery

Comment: Thank you, but this need to install other files also..(i.e: some .dll .sa). i just need to do this by only php.